# Java Util SQL Parser throws an exception for a correct statement

Tags: java, jsqlparser

My statement is

`new_call.cdctype=goal.cdctype`

When I call the method CCJSqlParser.SQLCondition() on this, I get an exception saying

```
Encountered " "=" "= "" at line 1, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "NOT" ...
    "LIKE" ...
    "ILIKE" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "NOT" ...
```

Any insight on why this happens?
I am checking join conditions and I think that this is an appropriate expression for join condition.

Code:

```
String sql = "new_call.cdctype=goal.cdctype";
CCJSqlParser parser = new CCJSqlParser(new StringReader(sql));
    String errorMsg=null;
    try {
        parser.SQLCondition();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        errorMsg=e.getMessage();
    }
    return errorMsg;
```

Comment: post your source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig a bit deeper into **JSqlParsers** grammer you will find, that a **SQLCondition** is only one of:

- in
- between
- isnull
- exists
- like 
  expression.

You specified a so called **RegularCondition**.

Here are two methods to parse your condition:

```
//Shortcut
Expression parseCondExpression = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression("new_call.cdctype=goal.cdctype");
System.out.println(parseCondExpression);

//from issue
String sql = "new_call.cdctype=goal.cdctype";
CCJSqlParser parser = new CCJSqlParser(new StringProvider(sql));
try {
    parser.RegularCondition();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way I am using JSqlParser V1.2. Your version seems a bit older, because the constructor parameter of the parser is now a **Provider**.

Comment: Testing this out. Hope this works. Sorry for the late reply, I was caught up with other work.